# QTableView: filtering vertical header labels

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` in a PyQt application with custom horizontal & vertical headers.
I'd like to find a way to filter the vertical header labels: the showed rows of the table would only be the one with a vertical header label matching the typed pattern.

It seems `QSortFilterProxyModel` only applies to `QTableView` content.

What would be the optimal way to perform this operation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I close this topic since I worked it around, hiding vertical labels, setting first column as not editable with my former labels and then applying `QSortFilterProxyModel` to my QTableView.